# Using hooks to get customer information

Tags: php, module, hook, prestashop

I'm trying to create a module that sends a sms to the customer upon order confirmation.

I got a hook called "hookActionPaymentConfirmation", which is called every time an order is set to payment accepted.

The code looks like this:

```
public function hookActionPaymentConfirmation($params)
    {
        mail("my@email.com", "yay", print_r($params));
    }
```

As you can see, it's currently just sending me the params array, however it seems to be emtpy :(.

I have been looking up on their documentation for some time now, and I cannot figure it out.

Hope someone can enlighten me? Maybe my approach is wrong?

Comment: use implode(',', $params), third argument is a string (http://php.net/manual/ro/function.mail.php), check the error.log

Comment: doing that is actually causing it to fail :D

Answer (score 0):

using `print_r($params, true)`

solved my problem :)